# Check if point lies on a line segment

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems, solution-verification

I know there are shorter solutions that use dot product, but I don't know what the logic behind doing so involves so I came up with something that I understand myself (i will research the dot product later).
Here is my solution, with comments to explain what I am doing at each stage. Is there anything I have missed in this? Please let know if you require the code to be 'more pseudocode' like and i will edit it. Thank you

```
BOOL pointLiesOnLineSegment(MKMapPoint aPoint, PMStraightMapLine aLine)
{

//1st, check if point is within triangle defined by line points
double minX = MIN(aLine.point1.x, aLine.point2.x);
double maxX = MAX(aLine.point1.x, aLine.point2.x);

double minY = MIN(aLine.point1.y, aLine.point2.y);
double maxY = MAX(aLine.point1.y, aLine.point2.y);

BOOL pointLiesInArea = ((minX<=aPoint.x<=maxX)  && (minY<=aPoint.y<=maxY));

if(pointLiesInArea)
{
    //2nd, check if passing in the x value into the line's equation gives the same y value, or vice versa (in other words check if point is on line)

    if((aLine.point2.x  - aLine.point1.x) == 0)
    {
        //undefined gradient for line, therefore:
        double xValueAlongStraightLine = aLine.point1.x;

        //since the line only has one x value throughout, the point must have the same:
        if(aPoint.x == xValueAlongStraightLine)
            return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        double lineGradient = gradientForLine(aLine);

        //insert aPoint.x into line equation and check if y value is the same
        double yValueFromLineEquation = (lineGradient*aPoint.x) - (lineGradient*aLine.point1.x) + aLine.point1.y;

        if(yValueFromLineEquation == aPoint.y)
            return YES;
    }
}

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: While several of us *do* know programming, this really seems like a question for [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Bye_World thank you for the suggestion. My question is more in the logic (Mathematics) than the 'how to apply the logic' (programming); that is why I came here. Should I change my question to just show steps in plain English?

Comment: I mistyped earlier.  Correction to comment: *1st, check if point is within **rectangle** defined by line points*.

Comment: It's usually easier for us to spot a problem with an equation or a plain English question than having to look through code.  That said, it's not exactly *disallowed* to post code.  I just think that this is a simple enough math problem that the guys at stackoverflow should have no problems with it and could help you improve your code as well as show you what might be wrong with the math.

Comment: Although, it looks like @Omnomnomnom is willing to do both for you. :)

Comment: @Bye_World it is not clear to me whether this is, at its heart, a math question or a programming question, since ultimately the question is about crafting an algorithm to solve a math problem.  At any rate, it's an easy question that shows effort on the part of the asker, so the way I see it there's no sense making a fuss.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're probably right.

Comment: Thank you for your time guys. I am asking about the logic, and not the programming. So if you wish me to edit the question to plain english I would be happy to do that.

Comment: It's been a while since CS 101, but this looks to me like it'll do what you need.  It seems Omnomnomnom agrees, so unless there's something specific about this algorithm that you'd like to know, I think you've got your answer -- and thus there's no need to edit it.

Comment: @Bye_World Oh yes it should be rectangle instead of triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the subroutines work as expected, this should do what you want it to.  That being said, there are certainly more efficient (or, at least, concise) ways of handling this problem, even if we don't bring dot products into this.

Some potential sources for error:

- what happens when `aLine` is defined by two identical points?
- what happens when `aPoint` is identical to one of the endpoints of the line?

If you're interested in a different method, say so.  For one, we can get rid of the "line equation" business.

Comment: I have considered both those questions (and others) in designing the code. If the line is defined by two identical points then the line equation would be x = aLine.point1.x; As you can see from the code it then checks if the single point has the same x value.
If the aPoint is identical to one of the line's end points that means aPoint.x and aPoint.y will pass check1 with a green tick since i am also checking for isEqualTo on the bounds, then for check2 substituting aPoint.x value into the lines equation will give aPoint.y, so another pass. Thank you for bringing these up ;)

Comment: Well, it looks like you have it under control.  A summary of what I had in mind: if you make a new line (call it `newLine`) between `aPoint` and `aLine.point1`, then (after the rectangle check in the beginning) it's enough to check whether `newLine` and `aLine` have the same slope.

Comment: Agh yes you are right, I could do that too. And yes it should be rectangle and not triangle. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: One more suggestion: you're really checking whether a point is on a line *segment*; a line has infinite extent. Renaming your procedure might be a good idea. Also: this is a much-studied problem in computer graphics; just about any graphics book will have very efficient algorithms, particularly for cases like "one point vs many segments" or "one segment vs many points," each of which can be done more efficiently than just repeatedly applying the "one point, one segment" approach.

Comment: @John my function is already called "pointLiesOnLineSegment:". I am writing this code as part of a bigger functionality that is not provided by the SDK that I am using. The functionality is indeed provided BUT: if I have a multiSegment line the SDK draws a virtual rectangle around this multisegment line and checks whether the touch point lies within that rectangle. I want precision: i want to check if the point lies on the actual line (any of the line segments that make up the whole line i.e).

Comment: Either I misread it or you changed the title of your question; I thought it said "check whether point lies on line", hence my comment. I see, looking at the code, that you DID call it a segment. Good Thing. :)

Comment: Oh, you comment was around the time I posted the question, so yes I Did edit the title and function name at that time. Thanks